# How to move a node to the position I touch in SpriteKit with Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game like Doodle Jump (without the accelerometer).

I have been trying to figure this out, but I can't seem to make it run as smoothly as I've been hoping.

Here is my code for my touches functions:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        lastTouch = touchLocation
    }    
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        lastTouch = touchLocation
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    lastTouch = nil
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if let touch = lastTouch {
        let impulseVector = CGVector(dx: 400, dy: 400)
        player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(impulseVector)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by it not running smoothly.  If you are testing on the iOS simulator, then it will run slower (due to emulation), but run better on an actual device.

Comment: Whenever I tap the screen, my sprite only moves up and to the right at a ridiculously fast pace. and tends to stay hugging the right side of the simulator screen.

Comment: And what are you trying to have it do?  I don't know how you want to control it.  Something like tap on this side of the screen to jump up and to the side the touch was on?  And yes, the up and to the right motion is what the 400 impulse on the x and y does, you may wish to slow it down.

Comment: I don't want it to go just up and to the right, I want it to go anywhere I tap on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm gathering, you want to change the `impulseVector` that is applied to the player based on where the touch is.  I would imagine the code looking something like this:

```
// At the top of your code
let scale = 0.5

// Update function
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if let touch = lastTouch {
        let xOffset = (touch.x - player.position.x)*scale
        let yOffset = (touch.y - player.position.y)*scale
        let impulseVector = CGVector(dx: xOffset, dy: yOffset)
        player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(impulseVector)
    }
}
```

This will pull the `player` node up with more force the further away it is from the touch.  If you are trying to pull the player with the same amount of force, no matter where they are (which may be more likely in this case), you would do something like this:

```
// At the top of your code
let xPlayerForce = 20
let yPlayerForce = 30 

// Update function
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if let touch = lastTouch {
        var xForce = 0.0
        var yForce = 0.0
        let xTouchOffset = (touch.x - player.position.x)
        let yTouchOffset = (touch.y - player.position.y)

        if xTouchOffset > 0.0 {
            xForce = xPlayerForce
        } else if xTouchOffset < 0.0 {
            xForce = -xPlayerForce
        } // else we do nothing

        if yTouchOffset > 0.0 {
            yForce = yPlayerForce
        } // here you can choose whether you want it to push
          // the player node down, using similar code from the
          // above if statement

        let impulseVector = CGVector(dx: xForce, dy: yForce)
        player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(impulseVector)
    }
}
```